# Adaptive thresholding Matlab-Opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, adaptive-threshold

I wanted to apply cv.adaptiveThreshold (opencv) through matlab on 8-bit single-channel uint8 image but I am always getting error. I have tried following code from this website: https://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/matlab/adaptiveThreshold.html

```
th = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,'Method',mean,'Type',binary,3,2);
```

and it gives me the error of Not enough input argument.
when I am running like this:

```
th = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img);
```

it is working properly but this is not what I want. I don't want to apply default methods and criteria.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have never tried it, but I am 99% sure that the solution is:

`cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,'MaxValue',255,'Method',mean,'Type',binary,'BlockSize ',3,'C',2);` . I mean, why did you specify just *some* of the option names?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Thanks. My bad. I have forgot to do that. But still there is problem with the binary.
th= cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,'Method',mean(img,1),'Type',binary,'BlockSize ',5,'C',5);

Undefined function or variable 'binary'. Do you have any idea? 
I have the function in my mathlab path.

Comment: try `'Binary'` instead of `binary` . No offense, but you may need to learn some basic programming/types.

Comment: No change ! still the same problem.

Comment: Note that I havent changed the uppercase, but the `'    '` around the word. Additionally, the default method is binary, so you can skip giving it to the function

Comment: yap. I did it but still. 
Error using adaptiveThreshold. 
Wrong number of arguments

Comment: BUT THAT'S A DIFFERENT ERROR.  Please you are not really looking and what you are doing, just randomly copypasting code. After giving the image `img`, the rest of the arguments need to be  pairs,    `...,'NameOfArgument`,Value,...` . Are you giving `'MaxValule'`?

Comment: * __Type__ Thresholding type, default 'Binary'. One of:
%       * __Binary__    `dst(x,y) = (src(x,y) > thresh) ? maxValue : 0`.  This is in the cv.adaptiveThreshold function. Do I have to add some extra variables?

Comment: This is my  code, after all:
th=cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,'MaxValue',255,'Method','Mean','Type','Binary','BlockSize ',3,'C',2); this error pops up: Unrecognized option BlockSize

Comment: Try to copy paste my answer. Note: you have a space after `BlockSize`

Comment: SO stupid of me, I have a scattered mind. Thanks for the help. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation. You are not following the function argument list

```
cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,'MaxValue',255,'Method','Mean','Type','Binary','BlockSize',3,'C',2);
```

should work

Comment: Thanks! Worked properly.